Which Noahide law covers assault?
I always get a little confused by the Noahide laws, because I've been told that they are more like seven categories than seven laws.
I'm a bit bothered that things like rape and assault are not mentioned specifically, but I'm assuming that they might be included under one of the seven?  Can someone tell me which one, and give me the reasoning why?

See this excellent answer: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/140459/31534, it should answer your question.
